# Docker: issue when using entrypoint+cmd but not when using just cmd

Tags: python, docker

I want to preface this by saying this is not a [general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) about the difference between cmd and entrypoint+cmd. I thought I understood the general difference and how to use them but I encountered possibly a more nuanced issue with entrypoint+cmd.

I was trying to write a simple image (call this image2) that pulls from another image (call this image1) which basically contains my environment. The purpose of this was that the environment is pretty static but I might want to make nuanced changes to the container that runs the code. The image I was having issues with looks like this:

```
FROM image1

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/conda/bin/python" ]
CMD [ "/tmp/script.py" ]
```

I wanted to write it this way to restrict the purpose of this container (running a python script). This however would throw an error when I ran it outside the container. It would start the script and run for a bit, but when it would get to some Pyspark code it would result in this:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Pyspark was suddenly looking to use python3 but I'm not sure why it started looking for that.

However, if I change the Dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM image1

CMD /opt/conda/bin/python /tmp/script.py
```

Then it runs fine without error. So I'm wondering if someone can explain why I'm able to do my script with CMD alone but not with ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I don't feel like `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]` really makes sense.  The `CMD` can still be any program on the system, but only if it's implemented in Python, and you still need to repeat the script name if you're overriding the command somewhere.  I might [make the script executable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#executable-python-scripts) so you don't need to explicitly say `python` at all, at least in the startup sequence.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "and you still need to repeat the script name if you're overriding the command somewhere"? I don't think I fully understand this. The idea was I wanted to limit the container to running python scripts. But I'm not very committed to this idea and might go with what you're saying

Comment: I think I got it working but I have to specify the full path like `docker run ... /tmp/script.py`. if I try to just pass it `script.py` it errors out with `/usr/local/bin/_entrypoint.sh: line 24: exec: script.py: not found`. Do you know if there's a way to just pass it the file name which would be located in /tmp/?

Comment: I figured it out by adding `/tmp/` to the PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dockerfile is fine... Though, there is a difference between `CMD arg1 arg2` and `CMD ["arg1", "arg2"]` (with brackets), so that would at least explain *some difference*.

> when it would get to some Pyspark code

You can set `ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/conda/bin/python` to change the interpreter Spark uses.